# Lucene project fatal error

Tags: java, lucene, stemming, porter-stemmer

I have a lot of text message, I run below lines of codes for them.

// tokenize term

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader(term));
```

// stemmize

```
tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);
```

SOMETIMES i get below error and sometimes no:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000025f8360, pid=1688, tid=7492
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer.stem(I)Z
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of   Windows
#
```

what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the analyzers like EnglishAnalyzer - http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html which will stem and tokenize it for you?

Comment: I have this line before above codes:       tokenStream = new StopFilter(LUCENE_VERSION, tokenStream, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());
but when I print the terms, they are not stemmized! so I used above codes for stemmizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your JVM. Its well documented on the lucene website that you cannot use java 1.7.0, because of a bug in the Oracle jvm.

Comment: But I`am using java version 1.8.0_05 in Eclipse

Comment: No you arent: JRE version: 7.0-b147

Comment: In help->about eclipse->installation details->configuration I saw java.version=1.8.0_05 before, but now I change other configurations and now Eclipse really uses java version 1.8.0. Thank u